# Qt Slot not being Called

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I got a program in which I connect with a QSignalMapper multiple signal from object to a slot in the main program:

```
class A()
{
    private:
        QSignalMapper * signalMapperRead_;
        std::vector<Service*> services_;
    public:
    void initConnection()
    {
        signalMapperRead_ = new QSignalMapper();

        connect(signalMapperRead_, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(readyToSendToService(int)));

        for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < services_.size() ; ++i )
        {
            connect(services_.at(i), SIGNAL(readyToSendToServer()), signalMapperRead_, SLOT(map()));
            signalMapperRead_->setMapping(services_.at(i), (int)i);
        }
    }

    int run()
    {
        initConnection();
        for(;;)
        {
             //do stuff;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    A * a  = new A();
    a->run();
    return app.exec
}
```

then, as the program is a kind of server i make him loop, and waiting for new client, ...

But the slot is never called. I am thinking that maybe it's because the program is always in the loop and never check if a signal has been emitted.

Can you please help me

Comment: Might step by step debugging be of some help?

Comment: Does the execution ever leave `run()`?

Comment: At the end of the program, except that no.

Comment: Maybe I can start a QeventLoop with a small timout in each loop cycle in the run

Comment: what is 'signalMapperSend_'?

Comment: it's a typo and should be signalMapperRead_, it has been corrected

Answer (score 2):

Don't use your own loop, create a QApplication and call its exec() method.

You have to call [QApplication::exec()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#exec) for Qt to deliver signals.

Edit for changed code: Just remove the for(;;)-Loop, it's uneccessary. QApplication::exec() has its own loop.

Answer (score 1):

> But the slot is never called.

The Qt documentation about [`QApplication::exec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#exec) says:

> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called [...].
>   It is necessary to call this function to start event handling. The main event loop receives events from the window system and dispatches these to the application widgets. [...]
>   **Generally, no user interaction can take place before calling exec()**. [...]

This means that it's the `exec` method that takes care of the signal-slot system. You are calling `A::run` (before the `exec` function) which contains an `for(;;)` infinite loop which will block the real loop from being executed leading to your signals to be lost.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a work-around. Beside I am not sure it's very efficient, my solution is to start a `QEventLoop` at every cycle of my `for(;;)` loop, and I made this `QEventLoop` quit on a `QTimer` timeout

Comment: Why don't you use the `QApplication` event loop instead of implementing your own? You are making work and problems for yourself.

Comment: Just drop your own loop already. All it does is burning your CPU with useless work. Creating (and deleting) an entire QApplication object in each loop iteration does not make it better.

Comment: I have to use my own loop, because It's a school project, we can use Qt for some stuff, but for example we can not use the QThread.